# PHP mailparse.so error - undefined symbol mbfl_convert_filter_flush

Tags: php, pecl

`sudo pecl install mailparse` ends with:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/mailparse.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/mailparse-2.1.6
configuration option "php_ini" is not set to php.ini location
You should add "extension=mailparse.so" to php.ini
```

After adding `extension=mailparse.so` to the `Dynamic Extensions` section of `php.ini`, running `php` prints this:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_convert_filter_flush in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Solution

`mailparse` must be loaded after `mbstring`, and `mbstring` is loaded by `/etc/php-5.5.d/mbstring.ini` which is read after `php.ini`.

Merely adding `mailparse.ini` to `php-5.5.d` will not work, because `ini` files are loaded alphabetically; though you could just name it `zz_mailparse.ini` instead.

Loading both extensions in **only**(sic) `php.ini` results in:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'mbstring' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'mailparse' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

That one's a mystery.

### Proof

```
$ echo '<?php echo extension_loaded("mailparse") ? "mailparse loaded\n" : "mailparse not loaded\n";' > ~/is_mailparse_loaded.php
$ php ~/is_mailparse_loaded.php
mailparse loaded
$ pwd
/etc/php-5.5.d
$ sudo mv zz_mailparse.ini mailparse.ini
$ php ~/is_mailparse_loaded.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/mailparse.so' - /usr/lib64/php/5.5/modules/mailparse.so: undefined symbol: mbfl_convert_filter_flush in Unknown on line 0
mailparse not loaded
$ sudo mv mailparse.ini zz_mailparse.ini
$ php ~/is_mailparse_loaded.php
mailparse loaded
$
```

Comment: This is somewhat old, but you can solve this by adding `; priority=30` on the second line of `mailparse.ini`. Then it will be symlinked to `30-mailparse.ini`, and loaded after `20-mbstring.ini`

Comment: I had this issue after upgrading form PHP 7.0 to 7.1.  Thanks for the solution! :)

Answer (score 6):

A quick one-liner:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'extension=mailparse.so' >> /etc/php.d/zz_mailparse.ini"
```

EDIT -
Some installations are in other dirs, just make sure:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'extension=mailparse.so' >> /etc/php-7.0.d/zz_mailparse.ini"
```

Comment: Warning for different installations. In my case I had to use `echo 'extension="mailparse.so"' > /etc/php-7.0.d/zz_mailparse.ini`